# How can i access created priorities at project level for different projects?

Tags: jira

**How can i access created priorities at project level for different projects?**

I'm trying to create different priority categories for different project, and I saw in the community that Jira has an option to create Priority Scheme and assign them to an specific project, but I cannot see that option, seems like is disable or hidden.

And I think that it provide priorities at global level. but i need at project level / project wise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which version of JIRA are you currently using? 
It was made available from JIRA software server 7.6

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jira-software-server-7-6

If you're using JIRA cloud, it looks like there is no priority scheme available.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JIRA-Cloud-alternate-for-creating-a-Priority-Scheme/qaq-p/682954

Comment: Yes, it's the Cloud instance and there are no priority schemes. In Jira Cloud, you can access all priorities with REST API: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-priority-get